# How can I drain a low pan into a drain at standard sink height?

Tags: plumbing, drain, bathtub

I am a dog groomer and the building I recently moved in was used as a Beauty Shop. The drain that my bathing tub is supposed to hook up at is located too high. I know the water will not drain uphill. Does anyone have any ideas on how to remedy this issue? I cannot put a drain in the floor due to concrete slab. I don’t care about passing inspection or code, only if it will work. Thank you.

Comment: We would need to have some idea about the situation to help. Otherwise the answer is just "lower the pipe". Please provide a photo, sketch, or clear written description of the plumbing and wall or floor structure.

Comment: Are you leasing the building? Is your landlord OK with you opening up the wall to adjust plumbing?

Answer (score 2):

Move the tub’s connection to the drain lower at the wall (may need to make a hole) or put the dog tub higher. There are not a lot of options here.

If all else fails then a solution would be to drain the tub into a container on the floor and have an electric (or manual) pump to pump the water into the drain as it gets close to full.

Comment: Presumably there was a line of lavatories on the wall at the right height for reclining chairs to position people's heads for hair washing. There would have been p-traps in drains at some height above the floor.  In a commercial setting like a beauty shop would the p-traps have been outside or inside the wall? Would the p-traps be above the floor or under the floor? If inside the wall, presumably they are still there. If the traps are low enough, the OP may be able to just cut off some of the drain above the trap to get it below the drain from the dog washing station. Open the wall and see.